# Node Index is zero at bitnodes

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitnodes

I have been running [Bitcoin Core on Gentoo](https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/net-p2p/bitcoin-qt) for some time. The current version I’m running is v22.0.0.

The node works well, ports are open and [bitnodes.io](https://bitnodes.io/) sees my node. So far so good.

The problem is that one of the parameters on bitnodes is zero for my node, and I can’t find a way to change it. The parameter is called NI (Node index).

What may be the issue? Does someone understand why this is happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to https://bitnodes.io/nodes/leaderboard/

```
NI = Nodes index
    NI = √(rs)
        rs = rank score
        r = rank of i
        i = p ∩ n
        p = peers returned in addr responses
        n = number of reachable nodes
        Largest i (99th percentile) is ranked 1 followed by the next largest i
```

So I guess you'd have to check that you have a large number of reachable peers.

But really I think this is something you'd probably have to ask bitnodes themselves about.